# When the BigPipe module is installed, the animation does not work (Drupal 8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drupal, drupal-8

On this page :

https://dev.s1biose.com/profil

There is a menu at the top right. It flashes green when the `.views-exposed-form` class is found with this JS code:

```
  if ($("#navbar-collapse-second .views-exposed-form").length) {
       $("#block-togglenavigationsecond .icon-navbar-second-alert").removeClass("icon-navbar-second-alert-disable");
  };
```

When the BigPipe module is installed, the animation does not work (under dev domain).

Here is my site with BigPipe uninstalled (under www domain):

https://www.s1biose.com/profil

The problem is that I do not see any difference in the HTML code.

Why does not the animation work with BigPipe ?

It must work on all browsers. But BigPipe creates problems on some web browser.

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCMsn.png)

Here is the complete JS file for my animation:

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-second').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('body').addClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('body').removeClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-second').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('body').addClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-second').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('body').removeClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-first .form-submit').on('click', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-second .form-submit').on('click', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-first .navbar-nav .dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
       $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle svg').removeClass("fa-plus-circle").addClass("fa-minus-circle");
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-first .navbar-nav .dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
       $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle svg').removeClass("fa-minus-circle").addClass("fa-plus-circle");
  });

  $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(this).parent().find('.panel-heading .collapse-change-icon svg').removeClass("fa-plus-circle").addClass("fa-minus-circle");
  });

  $('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(this).parent().find('.panel-heading .collapse-change-icon svg').removeClass("fa-minus-circle").addClass("fa-plus-circle");
  });

  $('.bs-tour-action-trigger').on('click', function () {
       $('#comment-ca-marche').modal('hide');
  });

  $('#block-boutonimportant').on('click', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
  });

  $('#block-boutoncharte').on('click', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
  });

  if ($("#navbar-collapse-first .views-manage-menu").length) {
       $("#block-togglenavigationfirst .icon-navbar-first-alert").removeClass("icon-navbar-first-alert-disable");
  };

  if ($("#navbar-collapse-second .views-exposed-form").length) {
       $("#block-togglenavigationsecond .icon-navbar-second-alert").removeClass("icon-navbar-second-alert-disable");
  };

  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () { 
       $(this).find("#block-menuprincipal .dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () { 
       $(this).find(".views-manage-menu .dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
  });

}(jQuery));
```